# How to upload pdf file to AWS Gateway Http Post to a .NET Core endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, .net-core, upload

I want to upload list of pdf files to AWS Gateway HTTP Post. Something with the AWS Gateway settings is messed up and I can't configure the gateway to receive media type and bind it to the C# class IFormFile. Here is my .NET core endpoint

```
 public class FileContainer
 {
     public IFormFile FilePayload { get; set; }

     public string Type { get; set; }
 }

 public class Request
 {
     public IList<FileContainer> Files{ get; set; }
 }
 
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Request request)
 {
     var files = request.Files.Select(x => x.FilePayload).ToList()
     //TODO: Do something with the files
 }
```

And here are my AWS gateway settings. First I have added the binary media types
[AWS Binary Media types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYfQS.png)

I also added the Content-Type header to the integration request.
These are the CloudWatch logs of the AWS gateway endpoint invocation

1. Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]
2. Endpoint request body after transformations: [Binary Data]
3. And when the request is sent to the .NET Core endpoint I GET 500 - Received response. Status: 500

It looks like AWS Gateway is receiving the binary data but can't send it to the .NET Core endpoint correctly

Here are the request headers as well

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------577290744247049779304216
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 161708
```

It works perfectly fine if I call the .NET Core endpoint locally without going through AWS Gateway.